# Get company field of organization?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I would like to know if anyone knows how to get company field of organization using `DirectorySearcher` or `PrincipalSearcher`?

Thanks a lot,

Víctor Castro

Answer (score 1):

Add "company" to the PropertiesToLoad property of the DirectorySearcher:

```
var ds = new DirectorySearcher(ldapRoot);
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");
var directoryEntry = ds.FindOne();
...
Console.WriteLine(directoryEntry.Properties["company"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the class I wrote a few years ago to pull this information.

I have not had to dig into the code for years, so it must work pretty good.

Hope you get some use out of it.

```
class ADProperties {
  public const string OBJECTCLASS = "objectClass";
  public const string CONTAINERNAME = "cn";
  public const string LASTNAME = "sn";
  public const string COUNTRYNOTATION = "c";
  public const string CITY = "l";
  public const string STATE = "st";
  public const string TITLE = "title";
  public const string POSTALCODE = "postalCode";
  public const string PHYSICALDELIVERYOFFICENAME = "physicalDeliveryOfficeName";
  public const string FIRSTNAME = "givenName";
  public const string MIDDLENAME = "initials";
  public const string DISTINGUISHEDNAME = "distinguishedName";
  public const string INSTANCETYPE = "instanceType";
  public const string WHENCREATED = "whenCreated";
  public const string WHENCHANGED = "whenChanged";
  public const string DISPLAYNAME = "displayName";
  public const string USNCREATED = "uSNCreated";
  public const string MEMBEROF = "memberOf";
  public const string USNCHANGED = "uSNChanged";
  public const string COUNTRY = "co";
  public const string DEPARTMENT = "department";
  public const string COMPANY = "company";
  public const string PROXYADDRESSES = "proxyAddresses";
  public const string STREETADDRESS = "streetAddress";
  public const string DIRECTREPORTS = "directReports";
  public const string NAME = "name";
  public const string OBJECTGUID = "objectGUID";
  public const string USERACCOUNTCONTROL = "userAccountControl";
  public const string BADPWDCOUNT = "badPwdCount";
  public const string CODEPAGE = "codePage";
  public const string COUNTRYCODE = "countryCode";
  public const string BADPASSWORDTIME = "badPasswordTime";
  public const string LASTLOGOFF = "lastLogoff";
  public const string LASTLOGON = "lastLogon";
  public const string PWDLASTSET = "pwdLastSet";
  public const string PRIMARYGROUPID = "primaryGroupID";
  public const string OBJECTSID = "objectSid";
  public const string ADMINCOUNT = "adminCount";
  public const string ACCOUNTEXPIRES = "accountExpires";
  public const string LOGONCOUNT = "logonCount";
  public const string LOGINNAME = "sAMAccountName";
  public const string SAMACCOUNTTYPE = "sAMAccountType";
  public const string SHOWINADDRESSBOOK = "showInAddressBook";
  public const string LEGACYEXCHANGEDN = "legacyExchangeDN";
  public const string USERPRINCIPALNAME = "userPrincipalName";
  public const string EXTENSION = "ipPhone";
  public const string SERVICEPRINCIPALNAME = "servicePrincipalName";
  public const string OBJECTCATEGORY = "objectCategory";
  public const string DSCOREPROPAGATIONDATA = "dSCorePropagationData";
  public const string LASTLOGONTIMESTAMP = "lastLogonTimestamp";
  public const string EMAILADDRESS = "mail";
  public const string MANAGER = "manager";
  public const string MOBILE = "mobile";
  public const string PAGER = "pager";
  public const string FAX = "facsimileTelephoneNumber";
  public const string HOMEPHONE = "homePhone";
  public const string MSEXCHUSERACCOUNTCONTROL = "msExchUserAccountControl";
  public const string MDBUSEDEFAULTS = "mDBUseDefaults";
  public const string MSEXCHMAILBOXSECURITYDESCRIPTOR = "msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor";
  public const string HOMEMDB = "homeMDB";
  public const string MSEXCHPOLICIESINCLUDED = "msExchPoliciesIncluded";
  public const string HOMEMTA = "homeMTA";
  public const string MSEXCHRECIPIENTTYPEDETAILS = "msExchRecipientTypeDetails";
  public const string MAILNICKNAME = "mailNickname";
  public const string MSEXCHHOMESERVERNAME = "msExchHomeServerName";
  public const string MSEXCHVERSION = "msExchVersion";
  public const string MSEXCHRECIPIENTDISPLAYTYPE = "msExchRecipientDisplayType";
  public const string MSEXCHMAILBOXGUID = "msExchMailboxGuid";
  public const string NTSECURITYDESCRIPTOR = "nTSecurityDescriptor";
}

public class ADUser {

  #region ' Properties '
  public string City { get; private set; }
  public string Company { get; private set; }
  public string Country { get; private set; }
  public string Department { get; private set; }
  public string EmailAddress { get; private set; }
  public string Extension { get; private set; }
  public string Fax { get; private set; }
  public string FirstName { get; private set; }
  public string HomePhone { get; private set; }
  public string LastName { get; private set; }
  public string UserName { get; private set; }
  public string LoginNameWithDomain { get; private set; }
  public string FullName {
   get {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName)) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)) {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
      } else {
        return FirstName;
      }
    } else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)) {
      return LastName;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
   }
  }

  public string MiddleName { get; private set; }
  public string Mobile { get; private set; }
  public string PostalCode { get; private set; }
  public string StreetAddress { get; private set; }
  public string State { get; private set; }
  public string Title { get; private set; }
  #endregion

  private ADUser(DirectoryEntry directoryUser) {
    FirstName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.FIRSTNAME);
    MiddleName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MIDDLENAME);
    LastName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.LASTNAME);
    UserName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.LOGINNAME);
    string userPrincipalName = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.USERPRINCIPALNAME);
    string domainAddress = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userPrincipalName)) ? userPrincipalName.Split('@')[1] : null;
    string domainName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(domainAddress)) ? domainAddress.Split('.')[0] : null;
    LoginNameWithDomain = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domainName, UserName);
    StreetAddress = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.STREETADDRESS);
    City = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.CITY);
    State = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.STATE);
    PostalCode = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.POSTALCODE);
    Country = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COUNTRY);
    Company = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.COMPANY);
    Department = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.DEPARTMENT);
    HomePhone = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.HOMEPHONE);
    Extension = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EXTENSION);
    Mobile = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.MOBILE);
    Fax = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.FAX);
    EmailAddress = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.EMAILADDRESS);
    Title = GetProperty(directoryUser, ADProperties.TITLE);
  }

  private static string GetProperty(DirectoryEntry userDetail, string propertyName) {
    if (userDetail.Properties.Contains(propertyName)) {
      return userDetail.Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static ADUser GetUser(DirectoryEntry directoryUser) {
    return new ADUser(directoryUser);
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddress)) {
      return string.Format("{0} <{1}>", FullName, EmailAddress);
    } else {
      return FullName;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will work provided you have already retrieved the company property in the directoryEntry. If you call the ADUser constructor with a DirectoryEntry object which has not loaded the company property, it looks like it will return null.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe. I've got another class I use in conjunction with these two small classes, but my other class is full of personal company specific information that the OP probably would not want. I'll leave it on here for reference, but concede that your version is the better answer.

Comment: Thanks Jaymz and jp2code,

I made the GetProperty method and worked.

I would like to know if is it possible to search for the company passing the value, not comparing the value?

Because this way, I have to compare value of all users, until the compare returns true.

Regards,

Víctor

Comment: Victor, to the best of my knowledge, that is a "security feature" of active directory - it can not really be searched from the outside.